# Automatically Drop and Recreate current indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, etl

I'm working on providing a method to allow for bulk updating our tables ( greater than 1M new or updated rows per update) and was interested in dropping the current indexes and recreating them after the updates.

I was wondering if anyone has a script to provide loose coupling of these operations so that if the indexes change over time, the update process does not change.

It seems like this is one of those things that the community has already probably solved.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL etc). There _will_ be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also by tagging it with a specific RDBMS your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have script that I use to query the system tables to capture all non-clustered indexes and disable then rebuild upon completion. The below is for use on standard edition, if you are on enterprise I would add the `ONLINE` option.

**Disable**

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '';
SELECT 
    @sql = @sql + 'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + o.name + '] DISABLE; '
FROM sys.indexes AS i
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'

EXEC (@sql)
```

**Rebuild**

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '';
SELECT 
    @sql = @sql + 'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + o.name + '] REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80); '
FROM sys.indexes AS i
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'

EXEC (@sql);
```

I like this method as it is very customizable as you can exclude/include certain tables based on the conditions as well as avoiding a cursor. Also you can change the `EXEC` to a `PRINT` and see the code that will execute and manually run it.

**Condition to exclude a table**

```
AND o.name NOT IN ('tblTest','tblTest1');
```

Comment: Awesome!  just going to invert the Not IN.  Much easier than the drop and create thing I was trying to do

Comment: You could also use `sys.tables` instead of `sys.objects` and save yourself to have to specify `WHERE o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'` all the time ....

Answer (score 4):

```
EXEC sp_MSforEachTable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? DISABLE'
```

and

```
EXEC sp_MSforEachTable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD'
```

is all you need if you want to do it for all tables and every index.

Comment: I got an issue with it. Tables with disabled Clustered index cannot get any rows inserted, as table becomes disabled.

Comment: `INSERT INTO` fails on a table with disabled clustered index. Data rows in a table with disabled clustered index are available for drop or rebuild operations only.

Comment: Well, yes, but it works for me. And I answered this 5 years ago and I'm not really an expert with SQL Server. So I can't help you. Please ask in a proper question!