# Programatically drop and recreate Oracle indexes for bulk update

Tags: oracle

Since Oracle does not support disabling normal indexes, I would like to programatically drop all indexes on a table before a bulk update and recreate them once the update is complete. I imagine this would require some custom PL/SQL. Can anyone offer a solution to this? Maybe someone here has already written such a script.

For reference, here is a solution for SQL Server: [Automatically Drop and Recreate current indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301383/automatically-drop-and-recreate-current-indexes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set head off
set echo off
set pages 1000
set lines 300
set feedback off
spool index_unusable.sql
select 'alter index ' || index_name || ' unusable;' from user_indexes where table_name='MY_TABLE';
spool off
@index_unusable.sql
```

do you bulk import setting this in your session before:

```
alter session set skip_unusable_indexes=true;
```

after the import:

```
set head off
set echo off
set pages 1000
set lines 300
set feedback off
spool index_rebuild.sql
select 'alter index ' || index_name || ' rebuild;' from user_indexes where table_name='MY_TABLE';
spool off
@index_rebuild.sql
```

If you have constraints you will need to disable them as well using:

```
 alter table mytable modify constraint constraint_name DISABLE keep index;
```